# Filling in Adobe Form with Ms Access, field is dropping leading Zeros

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, adobe, ms-access-2010

We are attempting to fill out a Adobe PDF form using, ms access and the Acrobat objects.  I have cut to the relevant snippets.  We are able to fill out most fields successfully, with the exception of fields (which should be strings), that have leading zeros (like a zip code).  The code below shows the problem.

```
   'Initialize Acrobat by creating the App object.
   Set objAcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
```

< snip >

```
   'Create the AVDoc object.
    Set objAcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

   'Set the PDDoc object.
   Set objAcroPDDoc = objAcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc

   'Set the JS Object - Java Script Object.
   Set objJSO = objAcroPDDoc.GetJSObject
```

< snip >

```
   objJSO.getfield("Zip Code").Value = "02110"
```

The Adobe form is filled out BUT the leading 0 inn the zip code is dropped.

Comment: Do you control the form?  If the field type is numeric then you will see this problem.  There is a specific type "zip code" available for this.

Comment: We do not control the form.  However we have investigated further and found that if there is a value in the field that can be interpreted as a number, adobe assumes the next value will also be a number.  If the value is say 'David' adobe has no problem accepting the zip code and preserving the zero.

Comment: Can we dynamically change the type of the field?

Comment: @akaphenom: There is no need to change the type of the field, because it will be a text field anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to make sure that preceeding zeroes are kept is to force a string. A simple way to do this is to add a space character to the string looking like a number, and it will then be rendered properly.

There may be implications if the form is used to submit back some data.

But if you don't have control over the form, that's what you have at hand.

Comment: We tried something similar - but the form through a type exception.

Comment: When you do something like that, you must keep the field with no format (which would require some control over the form…). There could be some kind of sneaky way to remove the formatting from the field, by injecting an accordingly set up FDF, which uses the /Before Javascript key.