# How does one maintain leading zeros in numbers of variable length from PDF forms to MS Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, pdf, pdf-form

I have hundreds of PDF forms on which electronic funds transfer (EFT) information is provided. My accounting people assure me that the leading zeros in the banking account numbers are important and need to be maintained. However, as the submitters of the forms use different banks with different account numbering schemes, the account numbers provided are of variable length.

After I compile the PDF forms into a spreadsheet, how do I format the account number field in the resulting CSV file to show the leading zeros where leading zeros were provided by the submitter without adding leading zeros to the account number where no leading zeros were used?

(I realize that the answer to this question is, "The leading zeros are not important." Please humor me by assuming they are.)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it's a csv file, so it's plain text. make sure the CSV is produced with the proper zero-padding. then just KEEP that particular field as text, so no numerical formatting strips "unecessary" zeroes.

Comment: @Marc B Whenever I open a csv file using excel, it automatically changes numbers to values without giving me a chance to set the fields to text.  I use a "CSV Converter" program that I custom built to get around this.  Is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: @Marc B - My problem is Acrobat is creating the csv file from the "Export Data From Multiple Forms" dialog box. Is there a way to tell Acrobat how to generate the csv file, e.g. set zero-padding? Or (better yet) is there a way to tell Acrobat to generate a txt file instead

Comment: One thing you can try is to add a space in front of the important field values before exporting. That's a simple way to force a string type.

Comment: @MaxWyss - I had previously seen your suggested answer to [akaphenom's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552439/filling-in-adobe-form-with-ms-access-field-is-dropping-leading-zeros); but I didn't fill out the forms that are collected. I suppose I can configure the forms in the future to include a space; but, as the provided responses that I have now don't have a leading space, I don't know how to make your suggestion work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the CSV file created by Acrobat from the "Export Data From Multiple Forms" dialog, I simply used VBA referencing "Acrobat" to "re-enter" the exact text of only the account number fields. This proved to be simpler than it sounds as the CSV file is generated with the forms' file names in the first column. It also avoids re-writing the entire process, instead coding only the part that was needed. The hardest part was finding how to keep the field in text format. In the end, I used

```
jso.getField("Account Number").valueAsString
```

The full code is as follows:

```
Sub GetAccountNumbers()
  Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
  Dim DisbForm As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
  Dim jso As Object
  Dim FormPath, FormFile As String
  Dim i, LastRow As Integer

  Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
  Set DisbForm = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

  'This is the path to the folder contaioning the forms
  FormPath = "C:\FolderOfPDFForms\"

  'This is the number of the row containing the last record in the CSV file
  LastRow = 5000

  For i = 2 To LastRow
    FormFile = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value
    DisbForm.Open (FormPath & FormFile)
    Set jso = DisbForm.GetJSObject
    Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = jso.getField("Account Number").valueAsString
    DisbForm.Close
  Next i

  Set AcroApp = Nothing
  Set DisbForm = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks, all, for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to programmatically assemble a tab-delimited (or CSV formatted, or formatted in any structured text format) text, make it into a Data Object, and export it. In my work, this occurs relatively frequently, and the most common is tab-delimited, but FDF or CSV have been created using that method too. As mentioned in the comment, adding a space (or any non-numeric character) should retain leading zeros, until you can set the format of the column in Excel.

Once you have the exported file, you can import it into Excel.